# Javascript Spec project?

Tags: javascript, testing

I'm currently working on a new Date class with some extra clock skew features. I want to fully test it so I can guarantee it is a drop in replacement for the existing Date class.

So coming from the Ruby world - we have a [rubyspec](http://rubyspec.org) project which is a test suite for all of the standard features, so that different interpreters can easily be compared.

I've been looking around for something similar in JavaScript. The only thing I've found so far is the [JavaScript Test Library](http://www.mozilla.org/js/tests/library.html). I've ended up porting some of them across to [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) so that I can run them easily in multiple browsers.

Is there something better I can use? It seems like this type of thing would be really valuable.

Comment: If you can avoid it, don't extend core objects. Instead, use utility functions that take in the object as an argument. That way, 1) you won't break core functionality, 2) your extensions can coexist with other frameworks (if they also behave).

Comment: Also +1 for the JS Test Library -- I didn't know one existed!

Comment: Ates, I've decided against extending the core object. I just want to make sure my class operates in exactly the same way as the core object, complete with the added functionality

Answer (score 0):

You should look in to JsTestDriver. It is a Google project. You can set it up so that it will run your tests across multiple browsers and OSes. Also, you don't need to write any kind of HTML test pages, you just write your tests in JavaScript, which is really nice.

http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/

Comment: Ronald, JsTestDriver looks really good - will definitely come in handy. At the moment thought I'm more interested in a test suite for testing the core functionality of JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

My choice is [Cucumber-JS](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js):

- Describe behaviour(Specs) in plain text.

  - [Gherkin](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Gherkin): [Business Readable, Domain Specific Language](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/BusinessReadableDSL.html)
- Reusability(language independent): even on other projects and other languages.
- Gerneration PDF/HTML Documents.
- [Custom Formatters](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Custom-Formatters)
- Supports Node.js and modern web browsers